# Help me get my 3D camera to look like the ones in RTS

Tags: xna, camera, rts

I am a newbie in 3D game development and I am trying to make a real-time strategy game. I am struggling with the camera currently as I am unable to make it look like they do in RTS games.

Here is my Camera.cs class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace BB
{
    public class Camera : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameComponent
    {
        public Matrix view;
        public Matrix projection;
        protected Game game;
        KeyboardState currentKeyboardState;
        Vector3 cameraPosition = new Vector3(600.0f, 0.0f, 600.0f);
        Vector3 cameraForward = new Vector3(0, -0.4472136f, -0.8944272f);
        BoundingFrustum cameraFrustum = new BoundingFrustum(Matrix.Identity);

        // Light direction
        Vector3 lightDir = new Vector3(-0.3333333f, 0.6666667f, 0.6666667f);

        public Camera(Game game) : base(game)
        {
            this.game = game;
        }

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            this.view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(this.cameraPosition, this.cameraPosition + this.cameraForward, Vector3.Up);
            this.projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, this.game.renderer.aspectRatio, 1, 10000);

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /* Handles the user input
         * @ param   GameTime gameTime
         */
        private void HandleInput(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            float time = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

            currentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
        }

        void UpdateCamera(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            float time = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

            // Check for input to rotate the camera.
            float pitch = 0.0f;
            float turn = 0.0f;

            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
                pitch += time * 0.001f;

            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                pitch -= time * 0.001f;

            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
                turn += time * 0.001f;

            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
                turn -= time * 0.001f;

            Vector3 cameraRight = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.Up, cameraForward);
            Vector3 flatFront = Vector3.Cross(cameraRight, Vector3.Up);

            Matrix pitchMatrix = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(cameraRight, pitch);
            Matrix turnMatrix = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.Up, turn);

            Vector3 tiltedFront = Vector3.TransformNormal(cameraForward, pitchMatrix * turnMatrix);

            // Check angle so we cant flip over
            if (Vector3.Dot(tiltedFront, flatFront) > 0.001f)
            {
                cameraForward = Vector3.Normalize(tiltedFront);
            }

            // Check for input to move the camera around.
            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
                cameraPosition += cameraForward * time * 0.4f;

            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
                cameraPosition -= cameraForward * time * 0.4f;

            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
                cameraPosition += cameraRight * time * 0.4f;

            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
                cameraPosition -= cameraRight * time * 0.4f;

            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.R))
            {
                cameraPosition = new Vector3(0, 50, 50);
                cameraForward = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
            }

            cameraForward.Normalize();

            // Create the new view matrix
            view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, cameraPosition + cameraForward, Vector3.Up);

            // Set the new frustum value
            cameraFrustum.Matrix = view * projection;
        }

        public override void Update(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime gameTime)
        {
            HandleInput(gameTime);
            UpdateCamera(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the initial view is looking in a horizontal direction. I would like to have an RTS like top down view (but with a slight pitch). Can you help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that problem is in your view matrix. The third parameter is so called "up vector". You should maybe se it to Vector3.Forward. Or you can calculate it as  this.cameraForward.cross(Vector3.right) - I don't know, if XNA syntax is like this, but there should be cross product of vector cameraForward and vector pointing to the right (or left).

Comment: the Matrix.CreateLookAt method does this internally. He is correct supplying Vector3.Up as the 3rd arg. Internally, it uses the Vector3.Up as a helper to determine the ortho up vector.

Answer (score 1):

```
view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, cameraPosition + cameraForward, Vector3.Up);
```

that second argument for the createlookat() is a camera target.

im currently working on my first 3d rts also and the way i have it set up
is my camera controls move a vector3 "target" which is set as my cameras target
and the in my update() after controls:

```
"cameraposition = new vectors3(target.x,target.y + zoom, target.z-zoom)"
```

where zoom is a variable that changes with the scroll wheel

and if you want to add in camera rotation you just apply some trig to the x/z

```
if (keyboardstatecurrent.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
    target = new Vector3(target.X + (float)(camSpeed * Math.Cos(CamRotation)), target.Y, target.Z + (float)(camSpeed * Math.Sin(CamRotation)));

if (keyboardstatecurrent.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
    target = new Vector3(target.X - (float)(camSpeed * Math.Cos(CamRotation)), target.Y, target.Z - (float)(camSpeed * Math.Sin(CamRotation)));

if (keyboardstatecurrent.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
    CamRotation = CamRotation + 0.1;

if (keyboardstatecurrent.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
    CamRotation = CamRotation - 0.1;
```

Camrotation is initialized as 0 and is in radians.

```
        cameraposition = new Vector3(target.X - (float)(Zoom * Math.Cos(CamRotation)), target.Y + Zoom, target.Z - (float)(Zoom * Math.Sin(CamRotation)));
```